# XQuery - are strings implicit nodes?

Tags: xquery, sequence, nodes

e.g.

Is it accurate to describe the folowing as a sequence of text nodes?

```
("foo", "bar", "baz")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, they aren't. Strings are not equal to text nodes, this is a sequence of strings.

Text nodes are of type `Node`, which again is an `item` (these are the most general data type in XQuery). Strings are derived from `xs:anyAtomicType`, which again is also an `item`.

Have a look at [XQuery's data type diagram](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-datamodel-30/#types-hierarchy).

### Determining the Type of an Item

A sequence of text nodes could be constructed using

```
(text { "foo" }, text { "bar" }, text { "baz" })
```

You can easily determine the type of a node using the `typeswitch` construct:

```
for $item in (text { "foo" }, "bar", 42)
return
  typeswitch($item)
    case text()
      return "text node"
    case xs:string
      return "string"
    default
      return "Something else"
```

### Inherited Types

You can also test for inherited types:

```
for $item in (text { "foo" }, "bar", 42)
return
  typeswitch($item)
    case node()
      return "node"
    case xs:anyAtomicType
      return "anyAtomicType"
    default
      return "Something else"
```